# rvest scraping, getting td for particular th (tranlsation from Python)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi StackOverflow users,

Sorry for a silly question.

My question is a bit general, but here's an example:
Suppose I'm scraping Wikipedia infobox info on official webpages of US cities. So for a given list of Wikipedia URLs I need last row of infobox (the box on the right of the page) with the information on website.
In Python I will do it in this way. However, I cannot understand how to do it in R. So

```
r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles")
if r:
    text = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
def get_website(soup):
    for tr in soup.find("table", 
                        class_="infobox")("tr"):
        if tr.th and 'Website' in tr.th.text:
            print(tr.td)
            s = tr.td.p.string
            return (s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular identifier for the td or th you want?

But if you want `tr` element for `table` with class `infobox` similar to your code, here is what I would do:

```
require(rvest)

# read the webpage
webpage <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles")

# extract the url-link element of table with class infobox
your_infobox_tr <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".infobox") %>% html_nodes(".url>a")

# extract the href link content
your_href <- your_infobox_tr %>% html_attr(name='href')
```

Or if you like a one-liner

```
your_wanted_link <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles") %>% html_nodes(".infobox") %>% html_nodes(".url>a") %>% html_attr(name="href")
```

FYI: if you do not know what `%>%` is,  it is a pipe operator which can be obtained by installing `magrittr` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, my task is to get the URL of a link (which is in "td" after "th" contains "website". So, I need the [href] attribute if in this row in "th" there is "website".

Comment: A little edit above will do :). That last row of infobox you mention has class `url` which has hyperlink `https://www.lacity.org/`  (I hope this is what you meant?) @Petr

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way in both Python & R via XPath.

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles")

html_node(pg, xpath=".//table[contains(@class,'infobox') and 
                              tr[contains(., 'Website')]]/tr[last()]/td//a") -> last_row_link

html_text(last_row_link)
## [1] "Official website"

html_attr(last_row_link, "href")
## [1] "https://www.lacity.org/"
```

I made an assumption that you really wanted the `href` attribute of the link in the last `<tr>` but the `las()` expression in the XPath was the essential ingredient. The last `td//a` says (essentially) *"once you find the `<td>` in the `<tr>` we just found, look where in the element subtree tree for and anchor tag"*.